# regex for viewparam on geoserver

Tags: java, regex, geoserver

> Geoserver 2.1-RC1

I am trying to create a valid regular expression that geoserver use to validate viewparams.

Basically I have a sql that end like this

```
table.field in( '%field%' )
```

where the %field% geoserver must change for the viewparams that came from a openlayers call.

The value for the %field% must be something like:

```
'cake'
'cheesecake','pie'
'cake or pie', 'pie','cheesecake'
```

I've managed to create this expression

```
^[\']+[\d,\w,\s]+[\']*([\,]*[[\']+[\d,\w,\s]+[\'])*
```

It works just fine on all the online regex tester I have found, but when I try to save on geoserver I got this error:

> Invalid regular expression `^[\']+[\d,\w,\s]+[\']*([\,]*[[\']+[\d,\w,\s]+[\'])*`: Unclosed character class near index 50 `[\']+[\d,\w,\s]+[\']*([\,]*[[\']+[\d,\w,\s]+[\'])*`

There is anyone who could give me a hint about it? I'm not very skilled at regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

it is here `[[\']` this `[[` should be `[`

But I have no Idea why the online regex testers have accepted it.

Comment: Probably because they are using PERL based regexps instead of java based ones.